# When I am passing a 2d array with the size of column it is showing some error?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

Here is my code where I am getting error:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int n;
bool is_attacked(int board[][n],int x,int y) //Here I am getting error
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(board[x][i])
        return false;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(board[i][y])
        return false;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(board[i][j]&&(x+y==i+j||i-j==x-y))
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

It is giving error in function parameters of `is_attacked` and the error coming is:

```
array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token
```

Could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance?

Comment: (1) `n` is uninitialized. (2) While sending 2D array as parameter if not both the indices of the array atleast the second index must be specified and that too a constant. And where is `main()` ?

Comment: @AditiRawat n is global  and due to lengthy code I have ignored it

Comment: Recommended read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function

Comment: Here I want to know what is wrong in my code since I am also providing the column size to the array?

Comment: Ok ! so it means the only option I have to use the 2D array is to make it global to escape this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is the parameter you pass as the index of the 2D array needs to be a compile time evaluable constant expression. And since you are inputting n at run-time it is giving you an error.
An alternate method could be you define a macro, say `#define MAX 10` and change your function signature to

```
bool is_attacked(int board[][MAX],int x,int y, int n)
```

I am assuming this is N-queens or K-knights sort of problem, so you could define the macro accordingly.